# how is it that CLLocationManager gets a location when Airplane Mode is ON

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

My app uses CLLocationManager to get location updates from the device.

I had assumed that when the device was in Airplane Mode, I would not get location updates.  But I do.

The reason I assumed this is because Apple says that Airplane mode turns off Wifi, Cellular, Bluetooth, and GPS.  See:  http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1355

So, how is it that I'm getting a location update with a coordinate that seems reasonable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've developed an app that heavily uses the user location, so I had to check this and other situations.

I've learned that when all the services are off (Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, Cell Data) 
CLLocationManager returns the latest known location, so, in this case, even if the device in Airplane mode it will return a location.

You can try this by getting your location, turn Airplane mode on and then go far from there, ask the location again.

**TL; DR:** It doesn't. It returns the latest known location.

Comment: I think you're correct, but it's weird because I thought pure GPS was purely passive (i.e. no radio transmission) so it would be kosher on a plane.

Comment: @Daniel : Even receivers can emit some radio interference ( usually from local oscillators).  Thus the FAA blanket ban.  Used to be one could ask the pilot for permission, but now they lock them up.

Comment: @Diego - Thanks - this sounds plausible, and I'll test it out.  Is this documented somewhere, or you just know from experience?

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate aeroplane coordinates from driving? Other than speed obviously..

Answer (score 0):

You can manually turn WiFi back on in Airplane Mode, and possibly get a GPS fix if you wait long enough, depending on the iDevice model.