# Get User's Current Location / Coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, location, cllocationmanager

How can I store the user's current location and also show the location on a map?

I am able to show pre-defined coordinates on a map, I just don't know how to receive information from the device.

Also I know I have to add some items into a Plist. How can I do that?

Answer (score 256):

To get a user's current location you need to declare:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

In `viewDidLoad()` you have to instantiate the `CLLocationManager` class, like so:

```
// Ask for Authorisation from the User.
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() 

// For use in foreground
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Then in CLLocationManagerDelegate method you can get user's current location coordinates:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
}
```

In the info.plist you will have to add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`
and your custom alert message like; AppName(Demo App) would like to use your current location.

Comment: yes sorry, I explained myself very bad. I mean if you could put this code into a working app and show the file because I am lost and I don't know where to place the functions and what does the final code look like. Thank you very much if you could.

Comment: Don't forget about `Import MapKit` + `CoreLocation` + adding `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in the class definition.

Comment: I feel startUpdatingLocation will be executed even before the user says "Allow" in the alert which appears, right?

Comment: This doesn't work. The OP is asking how to do this in SWIFT , NOT objective C. I still can't get it to work either.

Comment: @Yusha If this looks like Objective-C to you, then you've never seen Objective-C (nor Swift)

Comment: whats the difference between these two to get the location? ```manager.location.coordinate``` and ```locations.last! as CLLocation``` ?

Comment: You forgot to mention the implementation of the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.

Comment: `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` has been renamed to `Privacy - Location Always Usage Description`

Comment: You MUST declare `locationManager` as a global variable instead of a local variable in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: don't forget add this line: `locationManager.delegate = self`

Comment: If you want to have and even more precise location checker, use `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` instead of `kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters`.

Comment: For me I had to add below lines in plist file in swift 4.                                                  <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> <string>Description</string>

   <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
   <string>Will you allow this app to always know your location?</string>

   <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
   <string>Do you allow this app to know your current location?</string>

Comment: Also don't forget to `stopUpdatingLocation()` after you get it.

Comment: Most of this answer is still wrong. It goes against everything Apple shows in the documentation. It results in runtime warnings.

Answer (score 105):

you should do those steps:

1. add `CoreLocation.framework` to BuildPhases -> Link Binary With Libraries (no longer necessary as of XCode 7.2.1)
2. import `CoreLocation` to your class - most likely ViewController.swift
3. add `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to your class declaration
4. add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to plist
5. init location manager:

   ```
   locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   locationManager.delegate = self;
   locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
   locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
   locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
   ```
6. get User Location By:

   ```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
       print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
   }
   ```

Comment: new function: func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])

Comment: Step by step answer. But please update it. Its not working for now.

Comment: Step 5 is all wrong. It needlessly requests authorization even if it's already granted. And it starts updating location long before it's been determined if the user has permission.

Answer (score 70):

Update for **iOS 12.2** with **Swift 5**

> you must add following privacy permissions in plist file

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description</string>

<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description</string>
```

---

Here is how I am

> **getting current location and showing on Map in Swift 2.0**

*Make sure you have added **CoreLocation** and **MapKit** framework to your project* (This doesn't required with XCode 7.2.1)

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class DiscoverViewController : UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
        {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) 
    {
    
        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation
        
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        
        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here is the result screen

[image: a screenshot of the map, centered in Mumbai]

Comment: I run your code and I get a blank white screen. Is there a view or something I need to add to the storyboard?

Comment: Worked great for me in Swift 4, just had to add an underscore (prompted to by Xcode) so the locationManager line became:     func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])

Comment: The code in `viewDidLoad` is all wrong. It needlessly requests authorization even if it's already granted. And it starts updating location long before it's been determined if the user has permission.

Answer (score 40):

Import library like:

```
import CoreLocation
```

set Delegate:

```
CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

Take variable like:

```
var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
```

On viewDidLoad() write this pretty code:

```
 locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

Write CLLocation delegate methods:

```
    //MARK: - location delegate methods
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation :CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
    print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

    self.labelLat.text = "\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
    self.labelLongi.text = "\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)"

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print("error in reverseGeocode")
        }
        let placemark = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]
        if placemark.count>0{
            let placemark = placemarks![0]
            print(placemark.locality!)
            print(placemark.administrativeArea!)
            print(placemark.country!)

            self.labelAdd.text = "\(placemark.locality!), \(placemark.administrativeArea!), \(placemark.country!)"
        }
    }

}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error \(error)")
}
```

Now set permission for access the location, so add these key value into your **info.plist** file

```
 <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Will you allow this app to always know your location?</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Do you allow this app to know your current location?</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Do you allow this app to know your current location?</string>
```

[image]

**100% working without any issue. TESTED**

Comment: i have another language then it's not working . i want english language only.

Comment: The code in `viewDidLoad` is incorrect. It needlessly requests authorization even if it's already granted. It results in a runtime warning for calling `locationServicesEnabled()` on the main thread.

Answer (score 28):

[image: @wonderwhy I have added my code screenshot. pls check it. You will have to add <code>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in the plist for authorisation.</code>]

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription = Request permission to use location service when the apps is in background. in your plist file.

If this works then please vote the answer.

Comment: you can explain your answer more by adding code.if you wish

Comment: it would be nice to have the snippet of code using markup language rather than pasting a screenshot

Answer (score 28):

First import Corelocation and MapKit library:

```
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
```

inherit from CLLocationManagerDelegate to our class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

create a locationManager variable, this will be your location data

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

create a function to get the location info, be specific this exact syntax works:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
```

in your function create a constant for users current location

```
let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation // note that locations is same as the one in the function declaration
```

stop updating location, this prevents your device from constantly changing the Window to center your location while moving (you can omit this if you want it to function otherwise)

```
manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

get users coordinate from  userLocatin you just defined:

```
let coordinations = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude,longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
```

define how zoomed you want your map be:

`let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2,0.2)`
combine these two to get region:

```
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinations, span: span)//this basically tells your map where to look and where from what distance
```

now set the region and choose if you want it to go there with animation or not

```
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

close your function
`}`

from your button or another way you want to set the locationManagerDeleget to self

now allow the location to be shown

designate accuracy

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
```

authorize:

```
 locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

**to be able to authorize location service you need to add these two lines to your plist**

[image]

get location:

```
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

show it to the user:

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

This is my complete code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

  
    @IBAction func locateMe(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        
    }
    
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
        
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        
        let coordinations = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude,longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2,0.2)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinations, span: span)
        
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct code. You never verify if the user has permission or not. You request authorization every time the user taps the button. You start updating location without knowing if the users has permission.

Answer (score 22):

**Swift 3.0**

If you don't want to show user location in map, but just want to store it in firebase or some where else then follow this steps,

```
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
```

Now use CLLocationManagerDelegate on your VC and you must override the last three methods shown below. You can see how the requestLocation() method will get you the current user location using these methods.

```
class MyVc: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    isAuthorizedtoGetUserLocation()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    }
}

 //if we have no permission to access user location, then ask user for permission.
func isAuthorizedtoGetUserLocation() {

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorizedWhenInUse     {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}


//this method will be called each time when a user change his location access preference.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        print("User allowed us to access location")
        //do whatever init activities here.
    }
}


 //this method is called by the framework on         locationManager.requestLocation();
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("Did location updates is called")
    //store the user location here to firebase or somewhere 
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Did location updates is called but failed getting location \(error)")
}

}
```

Now you can code the below call once user sign in to your app. When requestLocation() is invoked it will further invoke didUpdateLocations above and you can store the location to Firebase or anywhere else.

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.requestLocation();
 }
```

if you are using GeoFire then in the didUpdateLocations method above you can store the location as below

```
geoFire?.setLocation(locations.first, forKey: uid) where uid is the user id who logged in to the app. I think you will know how to get UID based on your app sign in implementation.
```

Last but not least, go to your Info.plist and enable "Privacy -Location when in Use Usage Description."

When you use simulator to test it always give you one custom location that you configured in Simulator -> Debug -> Location.

Comment: Hi, Where are the locations (longitude, latitude), How often is reload the locations ?

Comment: @CristianMora when the locationManager.requestLocation is invoked, this is invoked  locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) where this is a Locations array and you can use one of them or show the user to pick the most appropriate. locations is of type  CLLocation and you can get longitudd,latitude from this object.If you need the user information only once then you don't need reload locations otherwise you can call requestLocation() as needed. Example a search request, you call requestLocation() first and then based on location give answers.

Comment: This code is all wrong. It results in a runtime warning for calling `locationServicesEnabled()` on the main thread. `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` should be called in the `didChangeAuthorization` delegate method if the current status is unknown. You never call `startUpdatingLocation` (which should be done in the `didChangeAuthorization` delegate when the status is authorized).

Answer (score 16):

first add two frameworks in your project

1: **MapKit**

2: **Corelocation** (no longer necessary as of XCode 7.2.1)

Define in your class

```
var manager:CLLocationManager!
var myLocations: [CLLocation] = []
```

then in viewDidLoad method code this

```
manager = CLLocationManager()
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
manager.startUpdatingLocation()

//Setup our Map View
mapobj.showsUserLocation = true
```

do not forget to add these two value in plist file

```
1: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

2: NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

Comment: The code in `viewDidLoad` is all wrong. It needlessly requests authorization even if it's already granted. And it starts updating location long before it's been determined if the user has permission. You never set the delegate so you can't response to authorization changes or location updates.

Answer (score 15):

Usage:

Define field in class

```
let getLocation = GetLocation()
```

Use in function of class by simple code:

```
getLocation.run {
    if let location = $0 {
        print("location = \(location.coordinate.latitude) \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
    } else {
        print("Get Location failed \(getLocation.didFailWithError)")
    }
}
```

Class:

```
import CoreLocation

public class GetLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    var locationCallback: ((CLLocation?) -> Void)!
    var locationServicesEnabled = false
    var didFailWithError: Error?

    public func run(callback: @escaping (CLLocation?) -> Void) {
        locationCallback = callback
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationServicesEnabled = CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
        if locationServicesEnabled { manager.startUpdatingLocation() }
        else { locationCallback(nil) }
    }

   public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                         didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locationCallback(locations.last!)
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        didFailWithError = error
        locationCallback(nil)
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    deinit {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" in the info.plist.

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to add the "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" in the info.plist

Answer (score 11):

```
import CoreLocation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    } 

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status != .authorizedWhenInUse {return}
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    }
}
```

Because the call to `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` is asynchronous, the app calls the `locationManager` function after the user has granted permission or rejected it.  Therefore it is proper to place your location getting code inside that function given the user granted permission.  [This is the best tutorial on this I have found on it](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/22/2/requesting-location-core-location).

Answer (score 10):

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()       
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();     
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else{
        print("Location service disabled");
    }
  }
```

This is your view did load method and in the ViewController Class also include the mapStart updating method as follows

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    var locValue : CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate;
    let span2 = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1, 1)    
    let long = locValue.longitude;
    let lat = locValue.latitude;
    print(long);
    print(lat);        
    let loadlocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                    latitude: lat, longitude: long            

   )     

    mapView.centerCoordinate = loadlocation;
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation();
}
```

Also **do not forget to add CoreLocation.FrameWork and MapKit.Framework in your project** (no longer necessary as of **XCode 7.2.1**)

Answer (score 5):

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

enum Result<T> {
  case success(T)
  case failure(Error)
}

final class LocationService: NSObject {
    private let manager: CLLocationManager

    init(manager: CLLocationManager = .init()) {
        self.manager = manager
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
    }

    var newLocation: ((Result<CLLocation>) -> Void)?
    var didChangeStatus: ((Bool) -> Void)?

    var status: CLAuthorizationStatus {
        return CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    }

    func requestLocationAuthorization() {
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
            //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        }
    }

    func getLocation() {
        manager.requestLocation()
    }

    deinit {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

}

 extension LocationService: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        newLocation?(.failure(error))
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.sorted(by: {$0.timestamp > $1.timestamp}).first {
            newLocation?(.success(location))
        }
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
            didChangeStatus?(false)
        default:
            didChangeStatus?(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Needs to write this code in required ViewController.

```
 //NOTE:: Add permission in info.plist::: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription


let locationService = LocationService()

 @IBAction func action_AllowButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
     didTapAllow()
 }

 func didTapAllow() {
     locationService.requestLocationAuthorization()
 }

 func getCurrentLocationCoordinates(){
   locationService.newLocation = {result in
     switch result {
      case .success(let location):
      print(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
      case .failure(let error):
      assertionFailure("Error getting the users location \(error)")
   }
  }
}

func getCurrentLocationCoordinates() {
    locationService.newLocation = { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let location):
            print(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                    return
                }
                if (placemarks?.count)! > 0 {
                    print("placemarks", placemarks!)
                    let pmark = placemarks?[0]
                    self.displayLocationInfo(pmark)
                } else {
                    print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
                }
            })
        case .failure(let error):
            assertionFailure("Error getting the users location \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its good approach

Answer (score 3):

All previous answers are not really following the correct set of steps correctly. When setting up the `CLLocationManager` you don't need to call `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` or `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` initially. And you should not be calling `startUpdatingLocation()` until you have verified you have authorization.

To get started, add the needed privacy setting if not done already. Select your app target and go to the Info tab. Under the "Custom iOS Target Properties" section right-click and select "Add Row". Scroll down to the "Privacy" entries and select either:

- "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description"
- "Privacy - Location Always Usage Description"
- "Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description"

depending on the needs of your app. For the value, be sure you enter a sentence that explains to the user *why* your app needs access to their location. You run the risk of your app being rejected by Apple if the given description isn't useful to the user.

Then use the following (heavily commented) code as an example for getting the user's location in a view controller:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Setup the location manager
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation // Or other desired accuracy

        // That's it for the initial setup. Everything else is handled in the
        // locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization delegate method.
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    // This is called as soon as the location manager is setup (in viewDidLoad)
    // This is called when the user responds to the privacy dialog
    // This is called if the user changes the privacy setting in the Settings app
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            // Request the appropriate authorization based on the needs of the app
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            // manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            print("Sorry, restricted")
            // Optional: Offer to take user to app's settings screen
        case .denied:
            print("Sorry, denied")
            // Optional: Offer to take user to app's settings screen
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            // The app has permission so start getting location updates
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        @unknown default:
            print("Unknown status")
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("Received \(locations.count) locations")

        // Some location updates can be invalid or have insufficient accuracy.
        // Find the first location that has sufficient horizontal accuracy.
        // If the manager's desiredAccuracy is one of kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters,
        // kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters, kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer, or kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
        // then you can use $0.horizontalAccuracy <= manager.desiredAccuracy. Otherwise enter the number of meters desired.
        if let location = locations.first(where: { $0.horizontalAccuracy <= 40 }) {
            print("Good location found: \(location)")
            // Call the following if you don't need any more updates
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

            // Do something useful with the found location
            // - show on a map
            // - Reverse geocode to get the address
            // - send to server
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Location manager error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a copy-paste example that worked for me.

http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/determine-users-current-location-example-in-swift/

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        determineMyCurrentLocation()
    }


    func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        // Call stopUpdatingLocation() to stop listening for location updates,
        // other wise this function will be called every time when user location changes.

       // manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
    {
        print("Error \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// its with strongboard 
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

//12.9767415,77.6903967 - exact location latitude n longitude location 
let cooridinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.9767415 , longitude: 77.6903967)
let  spanDegree = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2,longitudeDelta: 0.2)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: cooridinate , span: spanDegree)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

*100% working in iOS Swift 4   by: Parmar Sajjad*

Step 1: Goto GoogleDeveloper Api Console And create your ApiKey

Step 2: Goto Project install Cocoapods GoogleMaps pod

step 3: Goto AppDelegate.swift import GoogleMaps and

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("ApiKey")
    return true
}
```

step 4: 
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapview: UIView!
let locationManager  = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManagerSetting()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func locationManagerSetting() {

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    self.showCurrentLocationonMap()
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
func showCurrentLocationonMap() {
    let
    cameraposition  = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!  , longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 18)
    let  mapviewposition = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.mapview.frame.size.width, height: self.mapview.frame.size.height), camera: cameraposition)
    mapviewposition.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapviewposition.isMyLocationEnabled = true

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = cameraposition.target
    marker.snippet = "Macczeb Technologies"
    marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
    marker.map = mapviewposition
    self.mapview.addSubview(mapviewposition)

}
```

}

step 5:  open info.plist file  and Add below Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description ...... below a  Main storyboard file base name

step 6: run