# Zoom in on User Location- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I can't figure out how to get the map to zoom in on the user location from viewDidLoad. I tried setting a region, and that didn't work. This is the code I have, any tips?

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var MapViewLocationManager:CLLocationManager! = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: PFGeoPoint! = PFGeoPoint()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.delegate = self
   MapViewLocationManager.delegate = self
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.Follow, animated: true)
}
```

I have looked up the answers for this question but haven't found the answer in Swift or that actually works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
    let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = //insert latitutde

    let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = //insert longitude

    let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
```

I saw you said you tried setting a region. Maybe try doing it this way.

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess that is where I am stuck, how would I define the latitude and longitude of the user location?

Comment: @Caitlin you're welcome! I'm on mobile so I can't explain, but check this out:  http://youtu.be/pSjbMwR2A2U and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25698536 if the video doesn't help.

Answer (score 9):

On most apps, a 'current location' button is implemented. A simple way to do it is like this:

```
@IBAction func myLocationButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)

}
```

Once the user pans or zooms the map, the tracking will stop. So it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 8):

You have to try this.
It will zooming map.

```
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.050, 0.050)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.0225, longitude: 72.5714), span: span)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)`
```

Comment: and if you want to zoom more you just use smaller numbers in spam: `let spam = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001, 0.001)`

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var conscienceMap: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    conscienceMap.showsUserLocation = true
    conscienceMap.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.follow, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your code. Answers with only code aren't as good at helping others learn.