# Change the region (zoom) for mapView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, polyline

I have a map and I draw a destination between two pins and I have also always open one call out.

My problem is that I want to zoom out a little bit more but I tried to do it with this code and it didn't work.

```
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0275, 0.0275)
let coodinate = self.meLocation!
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coodinate, span: span)
self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

I assume that making the line for the destination do the problem:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 2.0/255.0, green: 202.0/255.0, blue: 246.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        renderer.lineWidth = 2.8



        return renderer

    }
```

So my question is how I can zoom out a little bit more by default.

EDIT:

I Followed [this guide](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/draw-route-mapkit-tutorial)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The level of zoom depends on the span. Try changing these values:

```
let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0275, 0.0275)
```

Edit:

As per discussion, padding is better suited for your Map.

Try padding the edges like this:

```
self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(self.mapView.visibleMapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(40.0, 20.0, 20, 20.0), animated: true)
```

Change the values for better fit.

Note: Call it after:

```
self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect), animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried a 0.1 too but when it draws the destination it zooms again at the default zoom that render has

Comment: Let me check that myself.

Comment: Follow that guide if you want http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/draw-route-mapkit-tutorial and my map height is 200px (just to test it as mine)

Comment: I have downloaded their project, I'm guessing you want to zoom out because you can't see the source & destination location in screen properly as they are at the very edge?

Comment: yes exactly, as I use the call out to be open I can't see one of the pins and the call out

Comment: I see that zoom angle is adjusted as accordingly the route & i can't find an API to adjust zoom level as of yet. I suggest you to add some padding over edges so that both pins are visible properly. I have done the same thing for GoogleMaps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129025/discussion-between-arpit-dongre-and-mike-vorisis).

Comment: If it works, do accept the answer. You're welcome :)

Comment: @ArpitDongre Is this applicable for polygon as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `setRegion` you want to zoom. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040667/zoom-in-on-user-location-swift) may help you to set region.

Thanks:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in my question I said I have tried this.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial refer this link