# MapView that is zoomed in on the users current location in Xcode iOS Development

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I've tried the following solutions:

- [Zoom in on User Location- Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040667/zoom-in-on-user-location-swift)
- [Get User's Current Location / Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296691/get-users-current-location-coordinates)
- [Determine User’s Current Location Example in Swift](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/determine-users-current-location-example-in-swift/)

But all I get is a map zoomed in on some other location, like San Francisco or somewhere in the middle east.

The top answer for solution3 looks like it shows how to print the users current location but it doesn't show how to use it with a map.

My **ViewController.swift** file

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing it on a simulator?

Comment: If you are testing on the simulator, it's not going to show your current location. Are you testing on a real device?

Comment: Yes I'm testing on the simulator, I didn't know I couldn't do that

Comment: Check this [location on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214416/set-the-location-in-iphone-simulator)

Comment: You can replicate your current location on the simulator by going to `Debug`, `Location`, `Custom location` and entering in your coordinate on the simulator (not Xcode). To get your current coordinate, just go to `maps.google.com` and get the coordinate off the URL.