# How do I access CLLocationManager from within Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-location

[Get User's Current Location / Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296691/swift-get-users-current-location-coordinates/31277543#31277543) has something that appears to be what I want:

> you should do those steps:
>
> 1. add `CoreLocation.framework` to BuildPhases -> Link Binary With Libraries
> 2. import `CoreLocation` to your class - probably ViewController.swift
> 3. add `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to your class decleration
> 4. Add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to plist
> 5. init location manager:
>
>    ```
>    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
>    locationManager.delegate = self;
>    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
>    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
>    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
>    ```
> 6. get User Location By:
>
>    ```
>    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
>        var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
>        let long = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
>        let lat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
>        //Do What ever you want with it       
>    }
>    ```

I've poked around in Xcode, but I don't see where BuildPhases -> Link Binary with Libraries, or anything that follows.

If this is the approach I want, where in XCode do I add CoreLocation.framework to Link Binary with Libraries? If this is not the approach I want, how do I take advantage of Core Location?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You no longer have to manually link system frameworks (such as CoreLocation.framework) to your project. Just do a `import CoreLocation` at the top of the Swift file, and the framework will be seamlessly added for you (assuming you have the "Link Frameworks Automatically" setting to "Yes", which it is by default).

If you want to link to it manually, just go to "Build Phases" in your target settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Project navigator, the folder showing thingy to the left in xcode, click the project icon the one in the root of the project named like your project. Then in the top of the main window you will see several options, one of them being `Build phases`. Click that and you will find the option to add linked binaries.

Project navigator -> click project root -> Build phases -> linked binaries -> Add core locations