# How to make sure that user is in a certain area or location?

Tags: php, http, geolocation, location, server-side

I want to make a timesheet web app. My app has employees and employers. I want to prevent employees from cheating and prevent them from clock in and out when they are not in specify area. There are some technologies like ip or HTML5 geo location API but they are not very powerful and in geo location API employee can send fake location from client-side to server-side. 
Employees clock in and out.

Is there any way to  detect if employee is in specify area or is connected to same network as employer is, or any other idea?

Comment: Your app must ask users to share their location, so you can know where they are, and, if they refuse to share their location, you fire them. You cannot get the location without permission.

Comment: I know this idea, but this is not solution. How can I prevent employees from sending fake location on server-side?

Comment: You will not ask "Please tell me your location". What you must do is make your app to get the GPS position from the operating system = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296691/swift-get-users-current-location-coordinates

Comment: Slap some ankle bracelets on them and call it a day. You trust these employees so little that you want to lock down where they can clock in/out from? What if they forget to clock out at the end of the day and remember once they get home? Now you are forcing them to clock out even more inaccurately. This is not a technological issue but a social one.

Comment: Why not just serve the app internally on the network? Then they can't access it from anywhere else?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson And if I want to clock in/out on my phone? What do you suggest for construction site employees whose location is always changing?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson because it is an web app or SAAS.

Comment: Then just check the IP of the use and compare it to the employers IP? (since you wanted to see if they were on the same network). Regarding GPS-position, that is not always 100% and can be way off (in cities with high buildings, for example or other areas where there are a lot of signal bouncing and objects disturbing).

Comment: There will always be work-arounds to anything. Trust geo location and you're going to have people sending fake locations. Trust the ip address and you're going to have people tunneling through proxies. I'm with MonkeyZeus. Make it easy and convenient, and build trust with them so they won't cheat the system.

Comment: @skagzilla I am not agree with "build trust with them so they won't cheat the system". How can I trust them without practical validation?