# how to use my location(latitude,longitude) of CLLocation at viewdidload()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


        let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

        mylat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        mylong = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.04, longitudeDelta: 0.04))

        totalMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

first.. i'm sorry for my english writning...

i used to `mylat` , `mylong` in that func ..
but i want to add user recently location with global variable
and i use that user location in `viewDidLoad`..

actually i need user `location(lat,long)` and many other location,
and then i use comparing opration with two location,
and i need to most of nearly location ..

help me

Comment: Id like to refer you to my answer in similar thread were I made a through explanation of how it works:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296691/swift-get-users-current-location-coordinates/38568439#38568439

Comment: i will follow you ^^

Answer (score 0):

The `CLLocationManager` works asynchronously. You can use in your `viewDidLoad()` but not as you might think.

You can register a callback like this:

```
var onLocationUpdate: ((CLLocation) -> ())?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    onLocationUpdate = { [weak self] location in
        // do something with the location
    }
}
```

and call the `onLocationUpdate?(YOUR_LOCATION)` in the `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` method