# Unable to build a bicycle route in Google maps

Tags: ios, swift, latitude-longitude, google-distancematrix-api, distance-matrix

i am wonder ! when i using  **origin1** and  **destinationA** not working

> status = "ZERO_RESULTS";

but if used **origin2** and **destinationB** it is working perfectly  do i missed anything

```
var origin = "55.930385, -3.118425"
var destination = "50.087692, 14.421150"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    durationDestance(origin: origin, destination: destination, mode:"bicycling")
  }
 func durationDestance(origin: String, destination: String, mode:String) {

            var urlString : String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=\(origin)&destinations=\(destination)&mode=\(mode)&key=AIzaSyAVOt9LLagNGSOI8O0ri1Sbahcl_q5AFYc";

            urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)!
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let url = URL(string:urlString)!
            session.dataTask(with: url) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, erorr: Error?) -> Void in

                print("url: \(urlString)")
                if let responseData = data {
                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments);
                        print(json);
                    }
                    catch{
                        print("do not serialization :)");
                    }
                }
                }.resume();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no cycle path between these points.
Try to select bicycle: [google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/55.930385,+-3.118425/50.087692,+14.421150/@52.637377,-3.2840714,5z/data=!4m10!4m9!1m3!2m2!1d-3.118425!2d55.930385!1m3!2m2!1d14.42115!2d50.087692!3e2)

[image]

> I tried to make a route by bike and car. It is impossible to build a bicycle route, and the route by car exists

### Swift 3 Full Sample

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var origin = "55.930385, -3.118425"
    var destination = "50.087692, 14.421150"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        durationDestance(origin: origin, destination: destination, mode:"bicycling")
        durationDestance(origin: origin, destination: destination, mode:"auto")
    }

    func durationDestance(origin: String, destination: String, mode:String) {

        var urlString : String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=\(origin)&destinations=\(destination)&mode=\(mode)&key=AIzaSyAVOt9LLagNGSOI8O0ri1Sbahcl_q5AFYc";

        urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)!
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string:urlString)!
        session.dataTask(with: url) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, erorr: Error?) -> Void in

            print("url: \(urlString)")
            if let responseData = data {
                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments);
                    print(json);
                }
                catch{
                    print("do not serialization :)");
                }
            }
            }.resume();
    }
}
```

### Swift 2.3 Full Sample

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var origin = "55.930385, -3.118425"
    var destination = "50.087692, 14.421150"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        durationDestance(origin, destination: destination, mode:"bicycling")
        durationDestance(origin, destination: destination, mode:"auto")
    }

    func durationDestance(origin: String, destination: String, mode:String) {

        var urlString : String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=\(origin)&destinations=\(destination)&mode=\(mode)&key=AIzaSyAVOt9LLagNGSOI8O0ri1Sbahcl_q5AFYc";

        urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet())!

        let session=NSURLSession.sharedSession();
        let url=NSURL(string:urlString)!
        session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data: NSData?,response: NSURLResponse?,erorr :NSError?) -> Void in
            print("url: \(urlString)")
            if let responseData=data{
                do{
                    let json=try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments);
                    print(json);
                }
                catch{
                    print("do not serialization :)");
                }
            }
            }.resume();
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: That's right. Google can't build bicycle road between your points. You have no errors.

Comment: i understand your point and i set that mode auto  . but not working

Comment: I add swift 2.3 sample. Try to compile

Comment: could you check my update code i am  fail to working

Comment: one thing your answer is fully correct that is working but i am not sure why my update section code not working my main goal is . get user current location and destination to calculate duration time and km .

Comment: You try to use location manager. Read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296691/swift-get-users-current-location-coordinates

Comment: yes  i am try with 77 and 41 voted ans but not working

Comment: most of with try that question answer but not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130641/discussion-between-cristan-lika-and-vasily-bodnarchuk).

Comment: could you check this answare please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155676/user-current-lat-and-long-value-not-working-the-distancematrix