# Swift UserLocation UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Hey does anyone know how to make a button that fills a UITextField with the users current address? I'm open to any frameworks or API's I just need push in the right direction, maybe a tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: Already answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296691/get-users-current-location-coordinates

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Solution:**

To get the users location in longitude and latitude first you will have to

1. Add `import CoreLocation` to your class
2. Add `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to your class declaration
3. Add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to your info.plist file. You simply do this by pressing the add button and just copy and pasting one either one of them into it. It should auto correct to `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` and then you can add a description in the box to the right of it. That description will appear in the pop up when the app asks to use the user's location.
4. You then need to initiate location manager. You can do this by using

   ```
   let manager = CLLocationManager()
   manager.delegate = self
   manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
   manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
   manager.startUpdatingLocation()
   ```
5. You can then get the user's location using

   ```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
   let locat = manager.location
   ```

   }

Now that you have the user's location in longitude and latitude, you'll have to use geocoding to convert it into an address. To do this you have to

1. Add `import AddressBookUI` to your class
2. Create a `CLGeocoder` such as `let geocoder: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()`
3. Implement a reverse geocoding function

   ```
   geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(locat!, completionHandler: {
       (placemarks, error) in
       if (error != nil) {
           //geocoding failed
       } else {
           let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]

           if pm.count > 0 {
               let pm = placemarks![0]
               let address = (pm.subThoroughfare + ", " + pm.thoroughfare + ", " + pm.locality + ", "  + pm.subLocality + ", " + pm.country + ", " + pm.postalCode)
               print(address)
               manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
           }
       }
   })
   ```

This function takes the users current location which we already figured out before and then takes each bit of the location, orders it correctly, and prints it into the console. It then stops updating the user's location.

Then finally, you can just change the text of the UIButton to that string containing the address.