# Not getting users current location in swift 4

Tags: swift, core-location, xcode10

Location is not being printed to console. I have had this exact code working before but since updating to Xcode 10 it is not print the users current location into the console.

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    determineMyCurrentLocation()
}


func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
    print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
{
    print("Error \(error)")
}
```

Info.plist:
[image]

Comment: In the code above?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, this question appears to have already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25698536/1361672)

Comment: I have already tried this, The location is still not being updated

Comment: literally nothing

Comment: The code you provided works when added to a new project, ensure your `info.plist` is set correctly and the application has access to location services: `Settings > Privacy > Location Services > [Your App Name]` is set to "Always"

Comment: updated with a photo

Comment: @matt I placed print statements in all 3 and all of them returned the print statement.

Comment: @matt I also placed a break point on locationManager.startUpdatingLocation and it is being called

Comment: @matt Yes I have

Comment: I just opened a different emulator and when my view controller load it didn't ask for authorisation, Should it?

Comment: @Gary Host Its better to test location services in a real device rather than simulators. If using simulator, you can simulate a location  via : Debug > Location > Custom Location..

Comment: @Sujal I have been doing both to no success

Comment: Are you importing CoreLocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your *Info.plist*. You need *all three keys*:

[image]

Fix that and the app will spring to life. I pasted your code into a project, set up the *Info.plist* as shown, and it worked fine.

You can actually omit "Always" starting in iOS 11, but you must have both "When In Use" and "Always and When In Use", even if you are planning to ask only for "Always".

The runtime was in fact telling you this all along in the Xcode console, but you apparently weren't looking at it. It says:

> The app's Info.plist must contain both NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription keys with string values explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Comment: for just _requestAlwaysAuthorization_ why does he need all 3?!

Comment: @Honey Don't look at me! I tried it with just Always and When In Use and got an error. Then I tried after adding Always and got an error. Then I added When In Use and the whole app sprang to life, as I said.

Comment: This issue happens *only* for Xcode 10 right? Nonetheless I guess it never bothers to add them all :)

Comment: @Honey You can actually omit "Always" starting in iOS 11, but you must have both "When In Use" and "Always and When In Use". It has nothing to do with the Xcode version; it has to do with the iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported `CoreLocation`?

Try to change your `locationManager` form

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
```

to

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

and then you don't need it in `determineMyCurrentLocation()`

I would also `let userLocation = CLLocation()` in the top of your class and then update your location.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation]){
    let newLocation = locations[0]
    let distance = userLocation.distance(from: newLocation)
    // using this to update my location every 100m
    if distance > 100 {
        userLocation = newLocation
    }

    print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
    print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step:1 -** import

```
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
```

**Step:2 -** use : MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate

**Step:3 -**

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var latitude: Double = 0.0
var longitude: Double = 0.0
```

**Step:4 -** In ViewDidLoad

```
 self.determineMyCurrentLocation()
```

**Step:5 -** define Func

```
func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    {
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        if (authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse || authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways)
        {
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
        else if (locationManager.responds(to: #selector(CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization)))
        {
             self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }
        else
        {
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
    {
        print("Error while requesting new coordinates")
    }

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    self.latitude = locations[0].coordinate.latitude
    self.longitude = locations[0].coordinate.longitude
}
```

> Insert in info.plist {Privacy - Location Usage Description , Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description ,Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description , Privacy - Location Always Usage Description}

Answer (score 0):

Confirm `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUseUsageDescription` are in your plist file.