# locationManager.location returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

i am using `swift4.2` and `Xcode 10` and i am trying to make `iOS` app uses location service and it gives me exception: 
**`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`**

so i tried to check if location returns nil so i copy my code and print location and it returns `null` , i simulated location in `Xcode` from **product**>**scheme**>**edit scheme**>**default location** and checked location in debug area and it simulated to location i choose any one know the problem?

```
import CoreLocation

class LocationVC: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentlocation:CLLocation!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
   }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        authorizelocationstates()
    }

    func authorizelocationstates(){
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            currentlocation = locationManager.location
            print(currentlocation)
        }
        else{
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            authorizelocationstates()
        }
        }
```

Comment: make sure to add it in plist

Comment: You have to implement the appropriate delegate methods for example [locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423615-locationmanager)

Comment: Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296691/get-users-current-location-coordinates

Comment: Your `authorizelocationstates` is likely to go into an infinite loop if the user does anything other than authorize location use. Please find some good tutorials on using Core Location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have run your code and I just added missing key **Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description** in `info.plist` file.

And I have made some changes in your code and get `nil` value because method getting called multiple time and when user give permission and method again called and going to print location detail but the fact is still`locationManager` variable has not user location data yet.

get location details in `locationManager` when delegate `didUpdateLocations` called

I have done some changes in your code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentlocation:CLLocation!



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     //   authorizelocationstates()
    }

    func authorizelocationstates(){
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            currentlocation = locationManager.location
            print(currentlocation)
        }
        else{
            // Note : This function is overlap permission
            //  locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
           //  authorizelocationstates()
        }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locationManager = manager
        // Only called when variable have location data
        authorizelocationstates()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        // Get Location Permission one time only
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        // Need to update location and get location data in locationManager object with delegate
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    }

}
```

[image]

Hope it will help you.