# How to get user's current location coordinates using MapKit and get the address of those coordinates [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mapkit, core-location

Im currently getting the address of the user using Search Field Location AutoComplete and once the user selects the location I show the location annotation too. I Now also want to include locate me feature which gets the user's current location coordinates using MapKit and find the address of those coordinates

**My Current Version:**
[image]

Comment: you should explore here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296691/get-users-current-location-coordinates

Comment: And to find the address use reverse geocoding: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation

Comment: Thanks @AnupamMishra

Comment: Thanks @DamiaanDufaux