# swift revise function to return value

Tags: swift, core-location

I have a function locationManager that prints out zipCode but everytime I change this function to return a String or implement a completion block, the postal code no longer gets assigned a value. Can someone show how to make this function return a zipCode. I think I have to use async or Concurrency not sure though

```
import CoreLocation
import CoreLocationUI

class locationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @Published var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    func requestLocation() {
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                    if let postalCode = placemark.postalCode {
                        print(postalCode)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error getting location: \(error)")
    }
    
    func status(){
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
            case .authorizedWhenInUse:
                print("")
            case .authorizedAlways:
                locationManager(CLLocationManager(), didUpdateLocations: [CLLocation()])
            case .denied:
                print("")
            case .notDetermined:
                print("")
            case .restricted:
                print("")
        @unknown default:
            print("")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change a delegate method's signature. This is why your attempt to change `didUpdateLocations` to return a value or have a completion handler results in it not working.

If you want to provide a way for a user of your `locationManager` class (please rename the class to `LocationManager` - class names should start with uppercase letters) then you should add a completion property or add a completion parameter to the `requestLocation` function. Then your `didUpdateLocations` can call that completion handler passing back the zip code.

Also note that a lot of your location manager code is wrong and needs to be fixed. You should never be attempting to directly call the delegate method yourself. See [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296691/get-users-current-location-coordinates/74915706#74915706) for a full example of properly setting up and using `CLLocationManager` to get a user's current location. I've adapted that code to fit your use case.

The following code assumes the user of your `LocationManager` class will call `requestLocation` each time it wants to get the zip code of the user's current location.

```
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject {
    private var manager: CLLocationManager?
    private var completion: ((String?) -> Void)?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func requestLocation(completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        self.completion = completion

        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager?.delegate = self
        manager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    }
}

extension LocationManager : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // Only handle location that is within the desired 10 meters
        if let location = locations.first(where: { $0.horizontalAccuracy <= manager.desiredAccuracy }) {
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
                var postalCode: String?
                if error == nil {
                    if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                        postalCode = placemark.postalCode
                    }
                }

                self.completion?(postalCode)
                self.completion = nil
                self.manager = nil
            }
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error getting location: \(error)")
    }

    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .denied:
            print("Denied")
        case .notDetermined:
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            print("Restriced")
        @unknown default:
            print("Unexpected")
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
let manager = LocationManager()
manager.requestLocation() { zipCode in
    if let zipCode {
        print("We got a zip code: \(zipCode)")
    }
}
```