# Swift CLLocationManagerDelegate never got fired

Tags: ios, swift, location

I have this silly issue where I have been debugging for a whole day:

I implemented LocationManager class to retrieve user's coordinate, it worked last night. Then suddenly it stopped working today, I ran `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` but `locationManager` delegates never got fired, no result nor error. The class is a singleton so it stayed there without being destroyed, I checked `locationManager.delegate` and it refers my class `LocationManager` (not nil)

I have read almost every post about CLLocationManager and I'm desperated.

Here is my Info.plist:

```xml
    <key>NSWidgetUsesLocation</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable Weather for Power Users</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enable Weather for Power Users</string>
```

and LocationManager.swift

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

// Usage
// LocationManager.Instance.getCoordinateString(() { coordinatesString
//  print("Current coordinates string: \(coordinatesString!)")
//)

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    static let Instance = LocationManager()
    
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var authorizeCompletion: (() -> Void)?
    private var updateCompletion: ((_ coordinateString: String?) -> Void)?
    
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
    }
    
    public func requestPermission(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if status != .notDetermined {
            completion()
            return
        }
        
        authorizeCompletion = completion
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    
    public var status: CLAuthorizationStatus {
        get {
            return locationManager.authorizationStatus
        }
    }
    
    func getCoordinateString(completion: @escaping (_ coordinateString: String?) -> Void) {
        print("LocationManager.getCoordinateString() \(status)", locationManager.delegate)
        
        if status == .denied || status == .restricted {
                //          print("LocationManager.locationManager(): ERROR Permission:", status)
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        
        if status == .notDetermined {
            completion(nil) // Temporary return basic weather
            
            requestPermission(completion: { [self] in
                updateCompletion = completion
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                    //              locationManager.requestLocation()
            })
            return
        }
        
        updateCompletion = completion
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    // MARK: CLLocationManagerDelegate
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("LocationManager.locationManager(): Authorization completed", status)
        authorizeCompletion?()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("LocationManager.locationManager(): didUpdateLocations")
        
        guard let location = locations.last else {
            print("LocationManager.locationManager(): ERROR No coodinate found")
            updateCompletion?(nil)
            updateCompletion = nil
            return
        }
        
        // Stop updating location after the first result
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        
        let latitude = String(format: "%.4f", location.coordinate.latitude)
        let longitude = String(format: "%.4f", location.coordinate.longitude)
        let result = "\(latitude),\(longitude)"
        
        // Call completion handler if it's set
        updateCompletion?(result)
        updateCompletion = nil
        
        print("LocationManager.locationManager(): Coordinate \(result)")
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("LocationManager.locationManager(): ERROR \(error.localizedDescription)")
        updateCompletion?(nil)
        updateCompletion = nil
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

I have tested:

- On iOS Simulators
- On all real devices through Testflight & Xcode debugging installs
- Even with my code reverted.

So far I have tried to create a clean project and put my LocationManager.swift and **it's working perfectly!?** on iOS simulator

Another funny note that even without Info.plist keys being added, the "clean project" I tested at least returns error, but not in my real project.

Here is my usage in "clean project" and it's working:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        LocationManager.Instance.requestPermission {
            LocationManager.Instance.getCoordinateString(completion: {coordinateString in
                print("GameScene", coordinateString)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your location manager isn't really setup correctly. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74915706/20287183) for a correct example.

Comment: Thanks @HangarRash, but could you please point out what part of my setup was not correct? Do I need to change my LocationManager to run after viewDidLoad()?

Comment: Your delegate doesn’t do anything in the didChangeAuthorization method. That’s where you need to check the status and handle all of the cases.

Comment: @HangarRash actually I do something in didChangeAuthorization, signaling user finished authorization, and my usage is `LocationManager.Instance.getCoordinateString()`, not in the init(). However I also mentioned that I created a "clean project" and this code worked wtihout a flaw. That's huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found the issue after 12hours of debugging.

Calling location in on startup immediately does not work, instead I wait for a second then it's working. I guess delegates was not assigned on time?

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
      LocationManager.Instance.getCoordinateString(completion: {coordinateString in
                print("GameScene", coordinateString)
            })
})
```