# LocationManager triggering didUpdateLocations twice instead of once for each location change

Tags: swift, core-location

I am trying to capture and save the location using LocationManager but having trouble with it triggering didUpdateLocations twice for every location change.  I need it to only do this once as it's filling up my data model with duplicates for every reading.

The following is triggering twice and saving twice for each change it detects:

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        /// Too slow, not driving
        guard let speed = locations.last?.speed, speed > AppDefaults.gps.drivingSpeedThreshold else {
            return
        }
        ///  We are driving so do stuff
        if let currentLocation = locations.last {
            locationUpdateCounter = locationUpdateCounter + 1
            if locationUpdateCounter >= 5 {
                updateRegion(currentLocation)
                saveLocation(location: currentLocation)
                locationUpdateCounter = 0
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my override init() where I set and start location tracking:

```
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        startUpdatingtLocation()
        LogEvent.print(module: "LocationManager.init()", message: "init finished")
    }
```

```
    func startUpdatingtLocation() {
        let authorizationStatus = locationManager.authorizationStatus
        if authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else if authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
        LogEvent.print(module: "LocationManager.startUpdatingLocation", message: "Location tracking started...")
    }
```

```
    func saveLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        do {
            // Access the sharedModelContainer
            guard let container = AppEnvironment.sharedModelContainer else {
                print("ModelContainer has not been initialized.")
                return
            }
            
            let context = ModelContext(container)
            
            let entry = GpsJournalSD(
                timestamp: Date(),
                longitude: location.coordinate.longitude,
                latitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
                speed: location.speed
            )
            
            context.insert(entry)
            
            print("Location saved: \(entry.timestamp) \(formatMPH(convertMPStoMPH( entry.speed))) mph")
        }
    }
```

I also have location updates allowed in Background Modes as well as the privacy locations set in the pinfo.list.

Here is where I see when I save.  It's filling up my data model with duplicates:

```
Location saved: 2024-02-25 16:48:31 +0000 6 mph
Location saved: 2024-02-25 16:48:31 +0000 6 mph

Location saved: 2024-02-25 16:48:36 +0000 21 mph
Location saved: 2024-02-25 16:48:36 +0000 21 mph

Location saved: 2024-02-25 16:48:41 +0000 36 mph
Location saved: 2024-02-25 16:48:41 +0000 36 mph
```

Comment: FYI - You should not have that `startUpdatingLocation` method. You should implement the `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization` delegate method. Only in there should you request authorization and start/stop location updates based on the current authorization.

Comment: Your problem is likely due to calling both `startUpdatingLocation()` and `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()`. Just call one as needed.

Comment: removed startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges().  Still have same issue.  removed startUpdatingLocations() from the init and just do on authorization and that works "when" I make the the initial authorization but when I start the app the app will need to know to start collecting this information.  I was doing that through the init(). This is an app that needs to continuously collect location information once authorized w/o a human starting/stopping every time

Comment: Once you create the `CLLocationManager` instance and set its `delegate`, then the `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization` delegate method will be called. Doesn't matter if authorization has never been granted or it was granted years ago. You simply call `startUpdatingLocations` if authorization has been granted. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74915706/20287183 for an example.

Comment: Woot!!! I followed your suggestions and it's cleaner now and doing a single trigger of the didUpdateLocations.  I've also isolated that I have a view where I was setting up LocationManager as a StateObject and making a call to a function w/in the LocationManager to retrieve the address based on latitude and longitude.  It looks like setting @SateObject var locationManager = LocationManager() triggers this.  So that leaves me with the challenge of how to retrieve up the address from a latitude and longitude with out triggering the didUpdateLocations and thus the double recording.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you have the makings of another question. Post a new question with all relevant code and details. And please don’t forget to upvote answers that you find helpful.

Comment: Was able to figure that out.  Key was to treat LocationManager as a singleton and make sure I used the one instance vs triggering a new session.  You've been a huge help!  Really.  I'm good shape.