# iOS app with location only works on iPhone and not on iPad, why?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, geolocation, core-location

I build an iOS app with a map (locations) in Xcode version 15.3. The app works on a iPhone (real + simulated) very well, but if I downloaded the same app on the iPad (real + simulated), no location can't be found. I already checked the settings on my real iPad (enabled location services) but still nothing works. What goes wrong?

Added picture info.plist and the code locationmanager:
[image: info.plist]
[image: info.plist]

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
        private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: .init(latitude: 37.334_900, longitude: -122.009_020),
        span: .init(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
    )

    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        if (location.speed >= 0) {}
}

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        degrees = -1 * newHeading.magneticHeading
    }
}
```

Comment: its hard to tell, did you check debug logs for your location manager delegate method ? If you try to access particular location services that require GPS+cellular to work, and your iPad has no cellular connection, it may not work as expected.'

Comment: I'm using in the code private let locationManager = CLLocationManager() and in info.plist Privacy - location When In Use Usage Description and  Privacy - Location Usage description. Where can I try to access location services that require GPS+cellular?

Comment: Please update your question to include relevant code, as text. This will include your use of `CLLocationManager`, its creation, setup, and delegates. Also show the relevant privacy strings in your Info.plist.

Comment: Alright, I added the most important code for the locationManager. Also I added the info.plist strings. Could it be also an issue with the iPad settings?

Comment: Be aware that non-cellular iPads do not have a gps chip. They rely on wifi network scanning to determine location. This may impact your ability to get an accurate location.

Comment: You are also requesting "always" location, but you don't have the required "always and when in use" location privacy string.  You should check the Xcode debug console for any location related messages  and perhaps implement [locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/3563956-locationmanagerdidchangeauthoriz) to validate the location permission that your app has

Comment: So much wrong. You make two authorization requests, both in the wrong place. You also start location updates before you even know if you have permission. You don’t implement two important delegate methods. Or at least you didn’t show them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74915706/20287183 for a proper example.

Comment: I checked the Xcode debug log again and an error shown up, namely "CLLocationManager(<CLLocationManager: 0x300b529f0>) for <MKCoreLocationProvider: 0x30277af80> did fail with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"". Also I changed the key "Privacy - Location Always Usage Description" to "Privacy - Location Always and When in use usage".