# Unable to show user current location in uikit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location, cllocationcoordinate2d

I am trying to display user current location when user granted to access user current location and also drop pin into current location of the user. I am using Xcode 15.3 and Swift version 5.10 . I have added the require filed into info.plit and define necessary function for it with outlet as well. But the problem is I got following warning  into console ..

**This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. Instead, consider waiting for the `-locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization:` callback and checking `authorizationStatus` first**.

This is error message into console and showing just Uk map into app when I run the app but I am expecting to show user current location with pin.

**Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"**

Here is the screenshot for info.plit ..

[image: info.plit]

Here is the screenshot when I run the app..

[image: app screenshot]

Here is the code ..

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        
        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
            
            locationManager.requestLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
       }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        
        if let userLocation = locations.first {
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.0, longitude: locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.0)
            
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        let myPin = MKPointAnnotation()
        myPin.coordinate = coordinate
        myPin.title = "Hey There"
        myPin.subtitle = "I am here"
        myMap.addAnnotation(myPin)
            
        }
    }
  
   
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedAlways:
            return
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            return
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .denied:
            return
        @unknown default:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: any Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `stopUpdatingLocation` as soon as you get a location update; your first update is likely to be very inaccurate. You can, of course, just ask the map to display the users location. Do you get a permission pop up?  What is the current location permission for your app in settings?  There is also no point in asking for permission if location is `restricted`; the user is unable to grant location permission in this case

Comment: I do not get the pop up . I am trying to run into real device it just showing uk map @Paulw11

Comment: If you don't get the pop up then one of two things is happening - Your `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization` isn't being called at all or you have previously denied location permission.  Set a breakpoint in `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization` and see what is happening.

Comment: You also need "Privacy - When in Use Usage Description"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74915706/20287183 for a proper example of setting up CLLocationManager. There are some key difference in that code versus your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure providing both `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` keys in Info plist file.

In `viewDidLoad`, you're able to fetch the current `authorizationStatus` by:

```swift
switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
case .notDetermined:
    //Request the first time
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
case .denied, .restricted:
    //TODO: Handle when user denied location permission
    //Force to open location permission in Setting for example
    break
default:
    break
}
```

Then `didChangeAuthorization` will trigger `startUpdatingLocation` because from now on, it's ready to work.

```swift
func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
    if manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse || manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedAlways {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

You can keep `stopUpdatingLocation` whenever the current location is focused like above depend on the requirement, or put it on `deinit`/`viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: You should not be checking the authorization status in `viewDidLoad`. Just check the status in `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization`. See the link I posted below the question for an example.

Comment: Oh, it seems like with `.delegate = self`, `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization` will be called when `isViewLoaded`. Although, I didn't see any notes about forcing making a call to `requestAlwaysAuthorization`, it's a bit redundant. +1.