# Why do I need to store a CLLocationManager to get the users location in MKMapView?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I want to get the user's location by setting `showUserLocation` property of `MKMapView` to `true`.
If I create a `CLLocationManager` and store it in a property, it works just fine.
However if I do not store it, just call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` on it like this:

```
if locationManagerStatus != .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
    CLLocationManager().requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
```

then it says:

```
Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

Comment: are you added NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription keys in plist

Comment: @JP_Mob Yes, I have added it.

Comment: just check below link i think this will helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063798/cllocation-manager-in-swift-to-get-location-of-user

Answer (score 2):

CLLocationManager has to "stay alive" to call its different delegate methods "didUpdateLocations", "didChangeAuthorizationStatus", etc. Even if you aren't using them it still has to be stored as a property to be used or else it will be deallocated when it false out of scope. I'd imagine this is because most of it's actions are async.

Comment: I have not set my class as the delegate of the location manager, so i don't know how it could call its delegate methods.

Comment: Either way, I don't think it is a sync task so when it falls out of scope in a method it is deallocated and it's processes are ended. By setting it as a property it stays alive and is allowed to finish.