# iOS didUpdateLocations throwing error iOS 8.0 Swift

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, ios8

Not sure what the issue is. I;m very new to swift and iOS8. But in general I have had no issues with CLLocationManager in iOS7. I've put as many cautionary ifs and checks and nils, but I keep getting this error. Please help!

So, on a button touch action, I start the location manager like this, along with the imagepicker camera -

```
//Start the location manager
        self.captureLocationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.captureLocationManager?.delegate = self
        self.captureLocationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        self.captureLocationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.captureLocationManager?.distanceFilter = 40
        ....
        {image picker code}
```

This is my code for didUpdateLocations

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!){
    if locations.count > 0 {
        var latestLocation = locations[locations.count-1] as CLLocation

        if !self.captureGeoCoder.geocoding {
            self.captureGeoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(latestLocation, completionHandler: { (placeMarks:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil{
                    if placeMarks != nil{

                        self.captureLocationPlaceMark = placeMarks[0] as CLPlacemark
                        println(self.objMomentModel.captureLocationPlaceMark.name)
                        self.captureLocationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
                        self.captureLocationManager = nil
                    }
                    else{
                        println("0 placemarks!")
                    }
                }
                else{
                    println("Oops, there was an error in reverseGeoCodeLocation!")
                }


            })
        }
    }
}
```

But my code craps out at

```
self.captureLocationPlaceMark = placeMarks[0] as CLPlacemark
```

with some weird error like:

```
(lldb)
```

Comment: This might be irrelevant, but it might not... In any case, this line is certainly wrong: `if error == nil` - you should not be examining `error` unless `placeMarks` is nil. Try just removing that part of the condition and see if things improve. If they don't, it was still right to remove it.

Comment: Why is it wrong? If there are errors, shouldn't I stop proceeding with the rest of the code?

Comment: What is the error? You only put in the lldb prompt.

Comment: Yes, I tried it and that was not the error. Looks like the issue was due to the variable scope. I put all of these as properties of the Controller class and it worked.     var captureLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var capturePlaceMark = CLPlacemark()
    var captureLocation = CLLocation()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this was seemingly a scope issue.

```
var captureLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
var capturePlaceMark = CLPlacemark()
var captureLocation = CLLocation()
```

Making all the core variables as properties helped with the scope and transfer of values between didUpdateLocation, didFinishPickingImage and the actual IBAction method.

Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar error because

`locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]!)`

Sometimes sends `nil` for locations. That means that your line:

`self.captureLocationPlaceMark = placeMarks[0] as CLPlacemark`

Will throw an exception force unwrapping the optional. There are two fixes - declare the delegate method with an optionally unwrapped locations or check against nil before you inspect locations.

Answer (score 0):

The cllocationmanager method has developed errors after upgrading from iOS, because there has been a change in the method.
Maybe if you use the same solution that presented the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25699474/4133150