# CLLocationManagerDelegate not receiving updates

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2, core-location

I have a view controller which hase these functions:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){

    print("loc")
}
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError){
    if(error.code == CLError.Denied.rawValue){
        print("error")
    }
}
```

It is direct child of this class:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class UIViewLocationManager : UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print(status.rawValue)
        switch status {
        case .NotDetermined:
            break

        case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                manager.requestLocation()
            } else {
                manager.startUpdatingLocation()
            }
            break

        case .AuthorizedAlways:
            break

        case .Denied:
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have this class

```
class CoreLocationController : NSObject {

    func requestLocationUpdate(delegate : CLLocationManagerDelegate){
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = delegate
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
```

then in AppDelegate I declare it like:

```
let coreLocationController = CoreLocationController()
```

But when I call `requestLocationUpdate(self)` from viewController which is child of `UIViewLocationManager` I dont receive any updates. However if I just copy-paste all methods to `CoreLocationController` and I do `locationManager.delegate = self` in `CoreLocationController init()` method than everything works fine.

Any ideas? I am really desperate because I have already tried so much aproaches but still cant get this working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locationManager` is a local variable within the `requestLocationUpdate` method. At the end of the call to `requestLocationUpdate`, `locationManager` will be destroyed and the `CLLocationManager` just created will have nothing referencing it, so it will be destroyed too, despite the fact that you have asked it to send messages to an extant `delegate`.

If the instance of `CoreLocationController` you have created is not destroyed - something always points to the instance - then changing `locationManager` to an instance variable should fix this:

```
class CoreLocationController : NSObject {
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
    func requestLocationUpdate(delegate : CLLocationManagerDelegate) {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = delegate
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```

The above code is working for me in a real iPhone 5 and in a simulated iPhone 6. The location update delegate code gets called. I did have to edit the plist as specified in [CLLocation Manager in Swift to get Location of User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063798/cllocation-manager-in-swift-to-get-location-of-user)

Comment: This solution is partialy working. By using it my didChangeAuthorizationStatus in super class is fired but I get no location update from child class ("loc" is never printed) even that I have location setup in simulator

Comment: Not sure about that, I've never used location in a simulator. Try a real device?

Comment: well I dont think that this is issue with simulator. It worked when I had all code in same class (CoreLocationController). I have seen some solution suggesting that this could be related to asigning delegate not on main thread. Maybe I will try something regarding threads tomorow. Anyway if anything else comes on your mind just post it

Comment: You have edited your plist? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050633/implement-cllocationmanagerdelegate-methods-in-swift/24056771#24056771

Comment: yes of course. WIthout it it wouldnt be even working when I put delegate to CoreLocationController